# Create a colormap for a histogram based off a data array

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, histogram, colorbar

I've looked in a variety of places for how to do this but haven't been able to find exactly what I need/find validation if this is even possible.

I have a 2d histogram of height on y axis (given by rdata1) and intensity on x axis (given by intensity). The histogram plots fine, but I'd like to scale the colorbar rather than have it normalised.

I have already defined a colourmap, and I simply want to scale it using my plotted data.

I would like to scale the data so that the colorbar (which currently runs from 0-1) scales from 0 to (number of points in bin)/(len(time)). This is so I can find out the probability of a point being in a certain intensity bin at a certain height. I was unsure whether to do this by making a second histogram (which I wouldn't plot) and exporting the max/min values from that to scale the colourbar, or using a number of for loops and lists to append values into bins for each height range and then max/min the number of values in those bins.

Code is attached below:

```
import numpy as np
import file_reader as fr
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colors import LinearSegmentedColormap
import matplotlib as mpl

time = [0.01649999991059303, 0.02584999985992908]
rdata = [-600.020751953125, -570.04150390625, -540.062255859375, -510.0830078125, -480.1037902832031, -450.1245422363281, -420.1452941894531, -390.1660461425781, -360.1867980957031, -330.2075500488281]
intensity = [[-37.32464981079102, -38.3233528137207], [-37.70231628417969, -38.05134201049805], [-38.27889251708984, -38.82979583740234], [-28.01022720336914, -27.68825912475586], [-8.408446311950684, -8.440451622009277], [-8.749446868896484, -8.750232696533203], [-9.431790351867676, -9.41820240020752], [-10.09048461914062, -10.23848724365234], [-10.84317588806152, -10.84869194030762], [-11.61933135986328, -11.67543029785156]]

range_bins = np.linspace(rdata[0],rdata[-1],(len(rdata)+1))
intensity_bins = np.linspace(-70,30,100)

intensity = np.array(intensity).ravel()
rdata1 = np.repeat(rdata,len(time))

cdict = {'red': ((0.0, 1.0, 1.0),
                 (0.25, 0.0, 0.0),
                 (0.55, 0.35, 0.35),
                 (0.75, 0.75, 0.75),
                 (1.0, 1.0, 1.0)),

       'green': ((0.0, 1.0, 1.0),
                 (0.25, 0.1, 0.1),
                 (0.55, 0.6, 0.6),
                 (0.75, 0.8, 0.8),
                 (1.0, 0.0, 0.0)),

        'blue': ((0.0, 1.0, 1.0),
                 (0.25, 1.0, 1.0),
                 (0.55, 0.2, 0.2),
                 (0.75, 0.1, 0.1),
                 (1.0, 0.0, 0.0))
        }

radar_map = LinearSegmentedColormap('radar_map', cdict)

H, range_bins, intensity_bins = np.histogram2d(rdata1,intensity,bins=(range_bins,intensity_bins))

fig = plt.figure()
X,Y = np.meshgrid(intensity_bins,range_bins)
plt.pcolormesh(X,Y,H, cmap=radar_map)

cax = fig.add_axes([0.95, 0.2, 0.02, 0.6])
cb = mpl.colorbar.ColorbarBase(cax, cmap=radar_map, spacing='proportional')
```

Any help with this would be massively appreciated. Sorry for the rather lengthy post.

Comment: Could you rather provide a [mcve] of the issue (such that one does not need to reverse engineer where the sample data needs to be placed in your code).

Comment: I have edited my post to hopefully provide further clarity to my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the moment, the colorbar is independend of the shown pcolormesh. 
If you link the colorbar to the pcolormesh, it will automatically scale to the minimum and maximum level of the plot. Use `plt.colorbar(pc)`, where `pc` is the return of the pcolormesh.

To normalize the histogram counts you may divide the histogram by whatever quantity you want, e.g.

```
plt.pcolormesh( X,Y,H/float(len(time)) )
```

Example:

```
fig = plt.figure()
X,Y = np.meshgrid(intensity_bins,range_bins)
pc = plt.pcolormesh(X,Y,H/float(len(time)), cmap=radar_map)

cax = fig.add_axes([0.90, 0.2, 0.02, 0.6])
cb = plt.colorbar(pc, cax=cax)
```

[image]